# Why is it not possible to kill Vim using the TERM signal from inside Vim itself?

Tags: shell, quit

Out of curiosity, I tried to `kill` Vim from inside `vim --clean`. I tried:

- `:!kill $PPID`
- `:call system('kill ' . getpid())`

However, nothing happens after running the commands above. The commands give no output, and `v:shell_error` is `0` in both cases. I noticed that `kill` works perfectly when run from outside Vim; Vim terminates when it receives the TERM signal: `Vim: Caught deadly signal TERM` `Vim: Finished.`.

Why is it not possible to kill Vim from inside Vim using the commands above?

Comment: Note that `!kill -9 $PPID` works for me (but `!kill $PPID`) doesn't, so it's probably about how vim handles signals... But I'm not enough of a linux guru to give more insights :) Also `kill` without `-9` works from a term buffer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A process can block, ignore, or catch signals.  You can see how a given process handles signals with this shell command:

```
$ cat /proc/PID/status | grep -E '^Sig(Blk|Ign|Cgt):'
                                       │   │   │
                                       │   │   └ caught signals
                                       │   └ ignored signals
                                       └ blocked signals
```

Replace `PID` with Vim's pid (process ID).

You'll get some output which could look like this:

```
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000003000
SigCgt: 00000001ef824eff
```

The numbers on the right are bitmasks written in hexadecimal.  To understand their meaning, you must convert them in binary; for example with `bc(1)`:

```
$ echo 'ibase=16;obase=2;ABC123' | bc
101010111100000100100011
```

The *index* of each non-zero bit stands for the number of a signal.

So, for example, if you have this bitmask:

```
SigCgt: 00000000280b2603
```

It can be converted in binary, and interpreted like so:

```
SigCgt: 101010111100000100100011
                       │  │   ││
                       │  │   │└ the signal 1 is caught (SIGHUP)
                       │  │   └ the signal 2 is caught (SIGINT)
                       │  └ the signal 6 is caught (SIGUSR1)
                       └ ...
```

Here is a [short shell script](https://github.com/lacygoill/config/blob/master/bin/signals-disposition) which I sometimes use while debugging a process:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  cat <<EOF >&2
usage:
  $0 <pid>
EOF

  exit 64
fi

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85365/289772
bitmask2signals() {
  i=0
  bits="$(printf 'ibase=16; obase=2; %X\n' "0x$1" | bc)"
  while [[ -n "${bits}" ]]; do
    i=$((i + 1))
    if [[ "${bits}" == *1 ]]; then
      printf ' %s(%s)' "$(kill -l "$i")" "$i"
    fi
    bits="${bits%?}"
  done
}

grep -E '^Sig(Blk|Ign|Cgt):' "/proc/$1/status" |
  while read -r a b; do
    printf '%s%s\n' "$a" "$(bitmask2signals "$b")"
  done
```

It's taken and adapted from this [unix.stackexchange.com answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85365/289772).  If I pass the pid of a Vim process as an argument to the script, here is its output:

```
SigBlk:
SigIgn: PIPE(13) ALRM(14)
SigCgt: HUP(1) INT(2) QUIT(3) ILL(4) TRAP(5) ABRT(6) BUS(7) FPE(8) USR1(10) SEGV(11) USR2(12) TERM(15) CONT(18) XCPU(24) XFSZ(25) VTALRM(26) PROF(27) WINCH(28) PWR(30) SYS(31) (32) (33)
```

Notice that `TERM(15)` is on the third line `SigCgt`.  `SIGTERM` is the default signal sent to a process when using `kill(1)` on linux.  As you can see, Vim catches it.

For a process, catching a signal means that it has registered a handler which will be automatically run whenever
the signal is received.  This handler will determine the behavior of the process.

For Vim, I think the handler is defined [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f4fcedc59d4cc5ae6b5270a933e8377030283c1c/src/os_unix.c#L1506-L1544).  Notice that the comment says that the caught signals are blocked when Vim is busy:

```
/*
 * Handling of SIGHUP, SIGQUIT and SIGTERM:
 * "when" == a signal:       when busy, postpone and return FALSE, otherwise
 *                           return TRUE
 * "when" == SIGNAL_BLOCK:   Going to be busy, block signals
 * "when" == SIGNAL_UNBLOCK: Going to wait, unblock signals, use postponed
 *                           signal
 * Returns TRUE when Vim should exit.
 */
```

My guess is that when you invoke `system()`, Vim is busy waiting for the shell command to finish; so it blocks the signal.  This is confirmed by the fact that the issue disappears if you use `job_start()` instead:

```
:call job_start('kill ' . getpid())
```

Because in that case, Vim doesn't need to wait for the command to finish.

Comment: And for the signals table, `man 7 ascii` or `kill -L`.